# How to get count and sum of records in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

I have a table that has the following fields:

1. AccountNumber
2. CurrentBalance
3. StatusID
4. LastTransaction

The StatusID can either be 1, 2 or 11.

I would like to show a count of the AccountNumbers in Statuses 1, 2 and 11 and Sum of CurrentBalance of all Accounts in each Status AND where the LastTransaction is older than 6 months.

My code so far:

```
SELECT Count(AccountNumber) NoOfAccts
      ,SUM(CurrentBalance) TotalBalance          
      ,StatusId

FROM Accounts
WHERE DATEDIFF (DAY, LastTransaction, GETDATE()) > 180
GROUP BY AccountNumber, StatusId
```

This code gives me individual rows for each account

```
|NoOfAccounts | TotalBalance | StatusId|
-----------------------------------------
|           1 |       364.24 |        1|
-----------------------------------------
|           1 |       856.25 |        2|
-----------------------------------------
|           1 |       189.24 |        1|
-----------------------------------------
```

and so on...

My sample Data is as follows:

```
|AccountsNumbr|CurrentBalance| StatusId| LastTransaction|
---------------------------------------------------------
|      215481 |       364.24 |        1| 2018=01-05     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      215587 |       856.25 |        2| 2017=05-02     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      216744 |       189.24 |        1| 2017=03-21     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      548756 |       693.15 |        1| 2017=08-20     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      235687 |       547.69 |        1| 2018=03-21     |
---------------------------------------------------------
|      895647 |       786.65 |       11| 2017=02-28     |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Would you care to post some sample data and expected results? This'll help you get an answer.

Comment: You shouldn't be grouping by `AccountNumber`

Comment: Then don't group by `AccountNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this below. Note the grouping. You had AccountNumber in the Group By.

```
--sample data
IF object_id('tempdb..#Accounts') is not null drop table #Accounts
CREATE TABLE #Accounts (AccountNumber INT, CurrentBalance MONEY, StatusID INT, LastTransaction DATE)
INSERT INTO #Accounts (AccountNumber,CurrentBalance,StatusID,LastTransaction) VALUES
(1, 100, 1, DATEADD(MONTH,-3, GETDATE())),
(2, 200, 2, DATEADD(MONTH,-4, GETDATE())),
(3, 50, 11, DATEADD(MONTH,-7, GETDATE())), -- older than 6 months
(4, 300, 1, DATEADD(MONTH,-8, GETDATE())), -- older than 6 months
(5, 10, 2, DATEADD(MONTH,-10, GETDATE())), --older than 6 months 
(6, 20, 11, DATEADD(MONTH,-12, GETDATE())), --older than 6 months 
(7, 5, 1, DATEADD(MONTH,-1, GETDATE())),
(8, 50, 2, DATEADD(MONTH,-2, GETDATE())),
(9, 100, 11, DATEADD(MONTH,-4, GETDATE())),
(10, 400, 1, DATEADD(MONTH,-11, GETDATE())) --older than 6 months

--query
SELECT  StatusID,
        COUNT(AccountNumber) AS 'Accounts',
        SUM(CurrentBalance) AS 'CurrentBalance'
FROM #Accounts
WHERE LastTransaction < DATEADD(Month,-6, GETDATE())
GROUP BY StatusID
```

output - according to the temp table data, this is correct

```
StatusID    Accounts    CurrentBalance
1              2           700.00
2              1           10.00
11             2           70.00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need  count for AccountNumber  you should now  use in count  and in group by in the same query

so you should use

```
SELECT Count(AccountNumber) NoOfAccts
  ,SUM(CurrentBalance) TotalBalance          
  ,StatusId

FROM Accounts
WHERE DATEDIFF (DAY, LastTransaction, GETDATE()) > 180
GROUP BY StatusId
```

or

```
SELECT Count(*) NoOfAccts
  ,SUM(CurrentBalance) TotalBalance          
  ,StatusId

FROM Accounts
WHERE DATEDIFF (DAY, LastTransaction, GETDATE()) > 180
GROUP BY StatusId,  AccountNumber
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's  doing to get the answer the OP wants, in all honesty. In the second query, `COUNT(*)` isn't going to give a total number of accounts if you're grouping by `AccountNumber`,

Comment: @Larnu  in the second query in answer  the resul should be for each statusID  and accountNumber  the number of not null  rows ..  .. anyway  the problem is that the OP can't use accountNumber in count and in group by  the OP must  choice between  . the use of accountNumber in count but not in group by or the use in group by but not in number  .